# .htaccess 301 redirect based on second to last and last directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm better with front-end development so I would really appreciate help with an .htaccess 301 redirect.

I want to 301 redirect /anything-here/rc/code/ to /anything-here/?rc=code

**Example 1:** //www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/rc/code/ should 301 redirect to //www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/?rc=code

**Example 2:** //www.domain.com/rc/code/ should 301 redirect to //www.domain.com/?rc=code

It should also retain a potential query string (any number of variables).

**Example 3:** //www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/rc/code/?variable1=value1&variable2=value2 should 301 redirect to //www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/?rc=code&variable1=value1&variable2=value2

It should not redirect if the second to last director is not 'rc' (exact match).

**Example 4:** //www.domain.com/any_directory/rc/other_directory/code/ should NOT redirect ('rc' is not second to last directory)

**Example 5:** //www.domain.com/code/rc/ should NOT redirect ('rc' is not second to last directory)

**Example 6:** //www.domain.com/arc/code/ should NOT redirect (no 'rc' directory)

**Example 7:** //www.domain.com/rc/ should NOT redirect ('rc' is not second to last directory)

I have another line that adds a trailing slash if it's missing so it's not relevant in this case. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Test
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(.*)/rc/(\w+)/?$
RewriteRule  ^   %1/?rc=%2&%{QUERY_STRING}  [R=301,L]
```

When not redirecting as in: `http://www.domain.com/code/rc/` the folder **rc MUST EXIST** otherwise an error 404 is generated.

You should not add a trailing slash to the query.

`http://www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/?rc=code&variable1=value1`

is different from:

`http://www.domain.com/any_directory/other_directory/?rc=code&variable1=value1/`

The last `variable1=value1/` will have a wrong value.